# Link to resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created model, view and controller:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

I run server and I see list of posts if I open in the browser http:\localhost:3000\posts.
Now I need to create link to this page. Something like:

```
<%= link_to("settings", { :controller => 'groups', :action => 'index'}) %>
```

But I get error on opening this page:

```
Couldn't find Group with ID=index
```

How ca I create link to http:\localhost:3000\posts and which action do I use in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the path helpers are excellent in these cases. You could do it like this:

```
<%= link_to("Posts", posts_path) %>
```

posts_path in this case will link to http://localhost:3000/posts

When you use use resources :posts in your routes.rb you automatically get a few path helpers. For example:

```
posts_path            # /posts
post_path(@post)      # /posts/1
edit_post_path(@post) # /posts/1/edit
new_post_path         # /posts/new
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a route such as:

```
resources :groups
```

In `config/routes.rb` then you will have the helper `groups_path`. You can use `rake routes` to see all of your routes and helpers, but in this case you will have:

```
groups_path
group_path(@group)
edit_group_path(@group)
```

[Polymorphic Routes Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html)